# Why does strcpy change the value of this one parameter?

Tags: c, string, strcpy

Hi this code I created capitalizes lower case letters. strcpy manages to copy the value of string to stringTwo, however I  was wondering why strcpy changes the value of string as well if I just used it as a parameter. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *capitalize(char *str) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {

        if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) {

            str[i] -= 32;

        }

    }

    return str;
}

int main() {

    char string[21];
    char stringTwo[21];

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%20s", string);

    strcpy(stringTwo, capitalize(string));

    printf("\n%s\ncapitalized: %s", string, stringTwo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy()` does _not_ change the value of `string`, but `capitalize()` does!

Comment: Please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), or encoding-specific code like this. All you really need is the [toupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) function, you don't even need to check if the character is lower-case or upper-case (or indeed a letter) first.

Comment: Why are you using the values 97 and 122? Use 'a' and 'z' instead? Makes the code more readable

Comment: and don't call `strlen()` inside the for loop as the length will be unnecessarily calculated again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `capitalize` function converts all letters to upper-case *in place*. That is, the string you pass as argument will be the one being converted.

If you don't want the original string to be modified, you need to do it in two steps:

```
strcpy(stringTwo, string);  // First copy the original string
capitalize(stringTwo);  // Then make all letters upper-case in the copy
```

Comment: or `capitalize(strcpy(stringTwo, string));` if it needs to be one step... Ok, looks ugly...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are changing the original one ( which is "string") and copying it to the new one (which is stringTwo).

If you have a chance for using a debugger, then you will see that in the first place you are changing the "string".

Edit:
Or you can try this if you prefer:
I changed the code a little bit.

```
    char *capitalize(char *str,char *str2) {
    strcpy(str2, str);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str2); i++) {

        if (str2[i] >= 97 && str2[i] <= 122) {

            str2[i] -= 32;

        }

    }

    return str2;
}
```

With this little change in your function, you are doing all the work in the function. You just type the `capitalize(string,stringTwo);`and this will do what you've wanted.